# Problema con Recyclerview no carga siempre los item

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Saludos a todos los experto

Tengo el siguiente problema, he implementado Billing Suscrripciones en Android, el codigo trabaja bien, el problema es que el Recyclerview a veces carga y muchas otras no, a veces carga a la primera, a veces hay que entrar a la activity unas cuentas veces, no entiendo el porque realiza ese bug, si pudieran cherquear el codigo y orientarme se los agradeceria.

Suscription.java

```
public class suscripcion extends AppCompatActivity implements PurchasesUpdatedListener {

    private TextView statuspremium, rangopremium;

    private BillingClient billingClient;
    private AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView_sub;
    private DocumentReference documentReference;
    private FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    private String userID;
    private MySubAdapter adapter;
    private Button cargarpremium;
    private ImageView ayudapremium, txtclose;
    private String status;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_suscripcion);
        this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);

        mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
        ayudapremium = findViewById(R.id.ayudapremium);


        ayudapremium.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(suscripcion.this, ofrecepremium.class));
            }
        });

        if (user !=null)
        {
            userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        }

        documentReference = mFirestore.collection("users").document(userID);
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

                status = value.getString("status");

            }
        });

        setupSubClient();
        iniciador();


        txtclose = findViewById(R.id.txtclosesub);
        txtclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                documentReference.update("premiumverificar", "no");
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(suscripcion.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private void iniciador() {

        statuspremium = findViewById(R.id.statuspremium);
        rangopremium = findViewById(R.id.rangopremium);
        recyclerView_sub = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_sub);
        recyclerView_sub.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView_sub.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView_sub.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, layoutManager.getOrientation()));
        cargarpremium = findViewById(R.id.cargarpremium);

        cargarpremium.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
        });

    }

    private void loadAllSubPackage() {

        if (billingClient.isReady())
        {
            Log.d("ERROR20", "onSkuDetailsResponse: ");
            SkuDetailsParams params = SkuDetailsParams
                    .newBuilder()
                    .setSkusList(Arrays.asList("vf_sub_unmes", "vf_sub_tresmes"))
                    .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
                    .build();
            billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSkuDetailsResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<SkuDetails> list) {

                    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK)

                    {

                            adapter = new MySubAdapter(suscripcion.this, list, billingClient);
                            recyclerView_sub.setAdapter(adapter);
                            recyclerView_sub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                        Log.d("ERROR5", "onSkuDetailsResponse: " + billingResult.getResponseCode());

                    }else
                    {
                        Log.d("ERROR6", "onSkuDetailsResponse: " + billingResult.getResponseCode());

                    }
                }
            });
        }else
        {
            loadAllSubPackage();
            Log.d("ERROR7", "loadAllSubPackage: Billing cliente not ready" );

        }

    }

    private void setupSubClient() {
        acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener = new AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK)
                {
                    Log.d("ERROR1", "onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse: " +
                            billingResult.getResponseCode());
//                    rangopremium.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                    tiemposub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else
                {
                    Log.d("ERROR21", "onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse: " +
                            billingResult.getResponseCode());
                }
            }
        };

        billingClient = BillingClientSetup.getInstance(this, this);
        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                setupSubClient();
                Log.d("ERROR2", "onBillingServiceDisconnected: " );


            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK)
                {
                    Log.d("ERROR3", "onBillingSetupFinished: " +
                            billingResult.getResponseCode());

//                    //Query
//                    List<Purchase> purchases = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
//                            .getPurchasesList();

                    billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS, new PurchasesResponseListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onQueryPurchasesResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @NonNull List<Purchase> list) {

                            if (list.size() > 0)
                            {

                                for (Purchase purchase:list)

                                    handleSubAlreadyPurchase(purchase);

                                Log.d("ERROR16", "onBillingSetupFinished: " +
                                        billingResult.getResponseCode());

                            }else
                            {

                                loadAllSubPackage();
                                documentReference.update("status", "user");
                                statuspremium.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                                Log.d("ERROR17", "onBillingSetupFinished: " +
                                        billingResult.getResponseCode());
//                            rangopremium.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                            tiemposub.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                            statuspremium.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                            recyclerView_sub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }

                        }
                    });






                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("ERROR4", "onBillingSetupFinished: " +
                            billingResult.getResponseCode());

                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void handleSubAlreadyPurchase(Purchase purchases) {

        if (purchases.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED)
        {


            documentReference = mFirestore.collection("users").document(userID);
            documentReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

                    if (value != null && value.exists()) {
                        status = value.getString("status");
                        rangopremium.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        rangopremium.setText(status);
                    }
                }
            });


            Log.d("ERROR11", "handleSubAlreadyPurchase: ");
            if (!purchases.isAcknowledged())
            {
                Log.d("ERROR12", "handleSubAlreadyPurchase: ");
                AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                        .setPurchaseToken(purchases.getPurchaseToken())
                        .build();
                billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener);
            }else
            {
                Log.d("ERROR13", "handleSubAlreadyPurchase: ");

            }
        }
        if (purchases.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.UNSPECIFIED_STATE){
            Log.d("ERROR14", "handleSubAlreadyPurchase: ");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> list) {

        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && list !=null)
        {

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
            String currentDateandTime = formatter.format(new Date());

            documentReference = mFirestore.collection("users").document(userID);
            documentReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

                    if (value != null && value.exists()){
                        status = value.getString("status");
                        rangopremium.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        rangopremium.setText(status);
                    }


                }
            });


            statuspremium.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerView_sub.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            documentReference.update("status", "PREMIUM");
            documentReference.update("bloqueo", 3);
            documentReference.update("premiumfecha", currentDateandTime);
            Log.d("ERROR8", "onPurchasesUpdated: " + billingResult.getResponseCode());

            for (Purchase purchase:list)

                handleSubAlreadyPurchase(purchase);


        }else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED)
        {
            Log.d("ERROR9", "onPurchasesUpdated: " + billingResult.getResponseCode());
            rangopremium.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            statuspremium.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            recyclerView_sub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            documentReference.update("status", "user");
        }else
        {
            Log.d("ERROR10", "onPurchasesUpdated: " + billingResult.getResponseCode());

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }


}
```

MySubAdapter.java

```
public class MySubAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MySubAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity;
    List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList;
    BillingClient billingClient;

    public MySubAdapter(AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList, BillingClient billingClient) {
        this.appCompatActivity = appCompatActivity;
        this.skuDetailsList = skuDetailsList;
        this.billingClient = billingClient;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(appCompatActivity.getBaseContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.listado_sub, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.txt_sub_name.setText(skuDetailsList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.txt_precio_sub.setText(skuDetailsList.get(position).getPrice());

        holder.setListener(new IReciclerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                        .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(position))
                        .build();
                int reponse = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(appCompatActivity, billingFlowParams)
                        .getResponseCode();

                switch(reponse)
            {
                case BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.BILLING_UNAVAILABLE:
                    Log.d("ERROR11", "BILLING_UNAVAILABLE");
                    break;
                case BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.DEVELOPER_ERROR:
                    Log.d("ERROR12", "DEVELOPER_ERROR");

                    break;
                case BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                    Log.d("ERROR13", "FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED");

                    break;
                case BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED:
                    Log.d("ERROR14", "ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED");

                    break;
                case BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_DISCONNECTED:
                    Log.d("ERROR15", "SERVICE_DISCONNECTED");

                    break;
                case BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_TIMEOUT:
                    Log.d("ERROR16", "SERVICE_TIMEOUT");

                    break;
                case BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_UNAVAILABLE:
                    Log.d("ERROR17", "ITEM_UNAVAILABLE");

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return skuDetailsList.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView txt_sub_name, txt_precio_sub;
        IReciclerClickListener listener;

        public void setListener(IReciclerClickListener listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txt_sub_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_sub_name);
            txt_precio_sub = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_precio_sub);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            listener.onClick(v, getBindingAdapterPosition());

        }
    }
}
```

activity_suscripcion.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/Snackbar_apoyo"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fondocurva"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/txtclosesub"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/statuspremium"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shadowColor="@color/negro"
            android:shadowDx="2"
            android:shadowDy="5"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:shadowRadius="10"
            android:text="@string/no_premium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <com.hanks.htextview.rainbow.RainbowTextView
            android:id="@+id/rangopremium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:colorSpace="150dp"
            app:colorSpeed="10dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/vinoayuda"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/haste_premium"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
            android:shadowColor="@color/negro"
            android:shadowRadius="10"
            android:shadowDx="2"
            android:shadowDy="5"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/que_ofrece_el_premium"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@color/blanco"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ayudapremium"
                android:background="@drawable/curvas"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_help"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cargarpremium"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/cargar_botones"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_desing"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_sub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>



    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

PD: He colocado un boton para recargar el Activity, y solo asi a veces carga y a veces no, solo para medio resolver ese bug, pero lo ideal es que me cargue el recyclerview a la primera

Answer (score 0):

inicialmente estas llamando recursivamente `loadAllSubPackage()` cuando el servicio no esta listo, realiza el siguiente cambio:

```
  private void loadAllSubPackage() {

        if (billingClient.isReady())
        {
         ...
         ...
         ...
        }else
        {
            loadAllSubPackage();
            Log.d("ERROR7", "loadAllSubPackage: Billing cliente not ready" );

        }

    }
```

**Tu método `setupSubClient()` cuando inicias la conexión del servicio no cuando el servicio se encuentra desconectado, llama tu método en `onBillingSetupFinished()` .**

```
billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                //setupSubClient();
               ...
               ...                
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK)
                {
                   setupSubClient();
                   ...
                   ...
                   ...
                  }
            }
       }
```